# Java->Selenium->java.io.FileNotFoundException: (The device is not ready) exception throws after updating excel path

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

//This is the updated path I want to Use

```
String filepath="D:\\Eclipse Workspace\\ValueAT\\Excel\\ValueATTestDataedited.xlsx";
```

Comment: It still throws error and takes old path :E:\Eclipse Workspace\ValueAT\Excel\ValueATTestDataedited.xlsx (The device is not ready)

Comment: Please edit your question and give code segments and explain what are you going to do

Comment: did you save excel sheet after edit in same location it seems excel is not is exact path